# How do you prove the trig identity $\frac{\sin^2x-\tan x}{\cos^2x-\cot x} =\tan^2x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to solve this trig identity. So far in class we have learned the Pythagorean, sum and difference, double angle, and half angle identities. I am just not sure where to start on this one. There is probably something that I am missing when I try to work it out. I need another set of eyes.

$$\frac{\sin^2x-\tan x}{\cos^2x-\cot x} =\tan^2x$$

Comment: Suggest writing all in terms of sine and cosine to start.

Comment: factor out by sin in numerator and by cos in denominator

Comment: That doesn't look correct: try for $\;x=\frac\pi4\;$ . Perhaps it is $\;\cos^2x\;$ in the denominator??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is $\;\cos^2x\;$ in the denominator, and for values when both sides are well defined: factor out $\;\sin^2x\;$ in the numerator, and $\;\cos^2x\;$ in the denominator:$${}$$

$$\frac{\sin^2 x-\tan x}{\cos^2 x-\cot x}=\tan^2 x\;\frac{1-\frac1{\sin x\cos x}}{1-\frac1{\sin x\cos x}}=\tan^2x$$